# connection failed error after disabling ATS

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I've made a login page on my app and added my web service which is HTTP:// so i got this error : "App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file."
Disabled ATS by adding:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Then got this error: Response code: 404

[Screenshot from in-app error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gqRO.png)

What should I do?
Sign-in web service works fine on Android app.

Comment: 404 means that the URL you are using id not found, please post more information about your API of contact the API developer.

Comment: how are u passing url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 404 error means that the connection was made and the server indicated that the resource could not be found. This means your App Transport Security setup is not blocking the request (or any requests which isn't the ideal although is sometimes necessary).

Check that the URL that you are accessing is correct and also check if any headers (e.g. content-type) need to be set.

Answer (score 0):

The web site hosting server will typically generate a "404 Not Found" web page when a user attempts to follow a broken or dead link. The 404 or Not Found error message is an HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

*So check on server side or cross-check what you are accessing.*